# Raster - pixel values not matching legend

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, pixel, stretch

I am a novice at working with raster data.

I extracted hundreds of .tiff files from a WMS and now I need to run zonal statistics on them using ArcGIS 10.5.1. The original map legend on the website shows rainfall values between 1mm to +3000mm.[image] These are the values I need for my zonal statistics. But the downloaded raster file the pixel values are 0-10 and the colormap has values 1-255.

[image]

I've tried stretching, but I'm still getting values up to 255.

What would be the correct process and tools (that I can hopefully run through ModelBuilder or ArcPy) to adjust pixel and classify as shown in the legend?

Comment: Could you expand a bit on the way you've extracted these rasters from WMS? I guess there might be the key to your question...

Comment: I extracted the capabilities from the geoserver. This is an example for requesting the annual rainfall of 1910 (I specified the layer, CRS, bounding box, format, size and date): http://geoserver.nationalmap.nicta.com.au/bom/wms?request=GetMap&service=WMS&layers=bom:annual_rainfall&styles=&srs=EPSG%3A4283&bbox=111.975,-44.525,156.275,9.975&width=5000&height=3883&format=image%2Fgeotiff&time=1910-01-01T00:00:00.000Z I ran a little script to get all the rasters, but they all use the same request.